# How to use properly the chrome.bluetooth.read function

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, arduino-ide

I am writing an extension for Google Chrome under Windows 8 to read data from an HC-05 Bluetooth module that is connected to an Arduino Nano circuit.

After the connection is OK I try to read data using chrome.bluetooth.read function, but the program is stacked in that point.

Can anybody give me some advice abut using that function?

```
    chrome.bluetooth.read(
            {socket: socket},
            function(myBuffer)

            {
                myView = new Uint8Array(myBuffer);
                log("mi buffer = " + JSON.stringify(myView));
            }
        );
```

Thank you,

JC

Answer (score 0):

It was very hard to use properly, so it was taken away and replaced with a much easier event:

[chrome.bluetoothSocket.onReceive](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetoothSocket#event-onReceive)

Example:

```
  chrome.bluetoothSocket.onReceive.addListener(function(receiveInfo) {
    console.log("Received " + receiveInfo.data.byteLength + " bytes");

    var bytes = new Uint8Array(receiveInfo.data);
    console.log("buffer = " + JSON.stringify(bytes));
  })
```